# What is an MC/Producer in Hip-Hop/Rap?

Tags: terminology, recording, production, rap

I saw this terminology used in an article I was reading and was wondering what an MC/Producer was.  I am not that familiar with rap or hip-hop terminology so was curious what it meant.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, the **producer** is the artist who makes the beat (the instrumental) of a song. 
The **MC** is the person who raps over that beat.

Wikipedia has it written as:
"Hip hop as a general rule consists of two elements: an instrumental track (the "beat") and a vocal track (the "rap"). The artist who crafts the beat is the producer (or beatmaker), and the one who crafts the rap is the MC (emcee)." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip_hop_production)

Comment: I would add that based on the way the question is phrased, "MC/Producer", the person in question is probably taking on both roles.  It may also be useful to make the distinction between the traditional roles for the terms producer and MC and how they're used in hip hop.